# Receiving NaN when trying to make calculations with 4 Digits Numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) code for calculating the price of the item the problem is that whenever the price is 4 digits the value that return is `NaN`.

```js
totalDiv: function() {
    var porcentage = +this.vmodel.form.percentage / 100;
    this.calculatedTotal = +this.vmodel.form.purchase_price / (1 - porcentage);
    this.vmodel.form.sell_price += this.calculatedTotal;
    return +this.calculatedTotal.toFixed(2);
},
```

Anyone could help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the actual values you're working with?

Comment: While it does often work, using `+(number as string)` to convert to a number is generally not as reliable as `parseInt`/`parseFloat`.